# How do I query Google Checkout using an order number?

Tags: android-pay, google-checkout

I have a merchant account on Google checkout.  I can view all the orders buyers put when I log on to https://checkout.google.com/sell/orders.  From there, I can search for a specific order number and view details about it.

I want to do the same programmatically, but after looking through the checkout API I can not find anything related to this issue.  Basically my input will be an order number and the output I want will be details regarding that ordre, or at least a boolean indicating whether that order exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the Order Report API to download a list of Google Checkout orders into a CSV file, then search localy. You are limited to the last 31 days.

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Order_Report_API